# Why am I receiving an error when trying to view a report in the report viewer webpart?

Tags: error, reporting-services, ssl

I am having trouble viewing reports in our company's SharePoint site using the report viewer webpart.  Here are the version details: SSRS 2008, MOSS 2007, IE9, Win 7 32-bit.  I can view the Sharepoint listing of the .rdl files but when I try to open one, I recieve a generic error: An Unexpected Error Has Occured.  Is this due to a missing IE plugin?  Security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, once again, this occured because I was not using HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Either use the methods in [this](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/%E2%80%9Can-unexpected-error-has-occurred%E2%80%9D-error-message-in-sharepoint/) link to turn on error messages, or you should be able to log on to the physical server to see the detailed error messages.

Comment: I looked at MOSS logs and figured out my issue - not using HTTPS.